# Highlight semicolmns when editting lua files

Tags: vimrc, highlight

I program in both C and Lua and therefore sometimes add a semicolmn in my Lua files. This is allowed by the standard, but my company's guidelines forbid semicolmns in lua code. Therefore, I would like vim to highlight any semicolmn it finds in a lua file. To achieve this, I tried adding the following to my .vimrc:

```
if _curfile =~ ".*\.lua"
    syntax match semicolmn ";"
    highlight semicolmn guibg=red ctermbg=1
endif
```

But this has some very weird effects: it does not actually work on any Lua file until I run

```
:so %MYVIMRC
```

After which it works, but only for the current tab. So I suspect that the entire .vimrc file might be broken, this is it:

```
let _curfile = expand("%:t")
if _curfile =~ "Makefile" || _curfile =~ "makefile" || _curfile =~ ".*\.mk" || _curfile =~ ".*\.mcrl2"
    set noexpandtab
else
    set expandtab
endif

if _curfile =~ ".*\.vhd"
    let g:vhdl_indent_genportmap = 0
    set tabstop=2
    set shiftwidth=2
    set softtabstop=2
else
    set tabstop=4
    set shiftwidth=4
    set softtabstop=4
endif

if _curfile =~ ".*\.tex"
    set tw=120
endif

colorscheme molokai
set shiftround
set autoread
set mouse=a
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set scrolloff=5
let g:rehash256 = 1
highlight Cursor guifg=white guibg=blue

set backspace=indent,eol,start

syntax on
set hlsearch

" Special save hotkey
noremap <Leader>s :update<CR>
" Remove whitespace
noremap <silent> <F5> :let _s=@/<Bar>:%s/\s\+$//e<Bar>:let @/=_s<Bar>:nohl<CR>
" Fixes copy paste behaviour for gvim
vmap <C-c> "+y
vmap <C-x> "+c
vmap <C-v> c<ESC>"+p
imap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+

set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'

let g:syntastic_vhdl_checkers = ['vimhdl']

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.S set filetype=armasm
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.h set filetype=c
cnoreabbrev X x
set keymodel=startsel

if _curfile =~ ".*\.lua"
    syntax match semicolmn ";"
    highlight semicolmn guibg=red ctermbg=1
endif
```

So, the actual question is: how do I modify my .vimrc so that any semicolmn in a lue file gets highlighted?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate target, you could never check things like the current file name from the vimrc file, as that will be loaded *once* only on startup, and *not* when loading new buffers. You should always put stuff like this in an `autocmd` or `after` directory (see other question for details), so you'll also want to change that `if _curfile =~ ".*\.vhd"` and `if _curfile =~ ".*\.tex"` to an autocmd.

Comment: You also want to use `setlocal` instead of `set` by the way, otherwise it'll affect all buffers, and not just the vhd/tex buffer. There's got to be a "how do I apply settings for a specific filetype?" kind of question already, but I can't seem to find it right now :-(

Comment: @MartinTournoij But still, the Makefile and vhd commands work perfectly, even when opening new tabs. Did you expect those to fail too?